# How can we custmize Check Box in Android?

Tags: android

I want to display Check box like Radio button though is it possible to give our own shape to the check box 
if possible than help me please thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. Use this code

```
<CheckBox  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:button="@android:drawable/btn_radio"/>
```

Comment: yes it is working but can we reduce the size and can change color ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your own shape or image for both of it's state and have to handle it in the code....